# How to add Multiple user acccount with check and SSH key using Bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, passwords, redhat

Based on my requirement in my **dev server**, I have Created a Linux function that will create a dev user,(Take the user's first name and create a Linux user )

we have a devs group in our developer server, and now want to create a Linux function for 10 plus developers (user)

as a requirement If any of the '$1' directories exist, it would throw a notice to the executor. our developer will have their own key my plan was not to copy the key. we could pass the key in when this is executed, or have this generate the key and output it on completion.

**I have tried this code:**

```
#!/bin/bash

CREATE_USER_NAME="pi"

# Create account
echo "============= now create an account ============="
sudo useradd -s /usr/bin/fish -m $CREATE_USER_NAME
sudo usermod -aG devs $CREATE_USER_NAME
sudo passwd $CREATE_USER_NAME

if getent passwd "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "yes the user exists"
else
    echo "No, the user does not exist"
fi
mkdir -p /home/santosh/.ssh
chmod 0700 /home/santosh/.ssh
touch /home/santosh/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 /home/santosh/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo chown -R santosh /var/www/html/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo mkdir -p /var/log/httpd/santosh-dev.jove.com/
sudo chown -R santosh /var/log/httpd/santosh-dev.jove.com/
#
```

**Output I Received:**

```
[santosh@skb Desktop]$ ./user1.sh
============= now create an account =============
[sudo] password for santosh: 
useradd: user 'pi' already exists
Changing password for user pi.
New password: 
BAD PASSWORD: The password is a palindrome
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
No, the user does not exist
```

what is the best advice here! I'm unable to figure it what is wrong here? can anyone guide me on it!

Comment: Both of those commands seem like reasonable ways to set the user password. Are you encountering some sort of errors?

Comment: we have a devs group in our developer server, now want to create a Linux function with the following requirements: 

getfacl /var/log/httpd
# file: var/log/httpd
# owner: root
# group: devs
user::rwx
group::---
group:devs:r-x
mask::r-x
other::---
want to make a Linux function on this dev server that will create developers? but with the tried command is get output as an error!

Comment: What command specifically is producing an error, and what is the error?

Comment: Mostly  Permission is denied issue. [santosh@skb Desktop]$ ./userbash.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home//.ssh’: File exists
chmod: changing permissions of '/home//.ssh': Operation not permitted
touch: cannot touch '/home//.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
chmod: cannot access '/home//.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www/html/-dev.abc.com/’: File exists